# Sequence problem find its character

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $(y_n)$ satisfies the relationship ${y_{n-1}}{y_{n+1}} + y_n = 1$ for all $n \ge 2$. If $y_1= 1$ and $y_2= 2$, What can you say about the sequence? What happens for other starting values?

Comment: Have you tried computing a few values?

Comment: I am unable to find for values n=7

Comment: As I commented to Johann Cigler's answer, $y_7$ is undetermined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arbitrary Initial values   $y_1=a,y_2=b$ (with $ab$ not zero) you get $a,b, \frac{1-b}{a},\frac{a+b-1}{ab},\frac{1-a}{b}$ . Then the sequence is periodic with period 5.
Thus for  $y_1=1,y_2=2$ the sequence should be $1,2,-1,1,0,1,2,-1,1,0,\dots.$

Comment: Beautiful ! (+1)

Comment: In $P^1\times P^1$ $(y_{n-1},y_n)\mapsto (y_n,y_{n+1})$ can thus be written as $(a,b)\mapsto (b,(1-b)/a)$. This is a Cremona transformation. Cremona transformations of finite order are completely classified; it would be interesting to identify a "minimal" model on which it acts as an automorphism.

Comment: If $(x_n)$ is the sequence defined by $x_n=-y_n$ for all $n$, then the relation becomes $x_{n-1}x_{n+1}=x_n+1$. So the elements are cluster variables in a [cluster algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_algebra) of type $A_2$.

Comment: Except that when $y_{n-2} = 0$, $y_n$ is undefined if $y_{n-1} \ne 1$, undetermined if $y_{n-1}=1$.  So in the case $y_1=1$, $y_2=2$ it should actually be $1,2,-1,1,0,1,undetermined,\ldots$.